# How to get coordinates from a Wikipedia page through API?

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I want to get the coordinates of a Wikipedia page through their API. I want to put the page title as 'titles' parameter. I have searched SO for a solution but seems they are scrapping the page then extracting. Is it possible through their API?

[image: Kinkaku-ji]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use [Wikipedia API](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Bcoordinates). For your example with [Kinkaku-ji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinkaku-ji) the query will be:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=coordinates&titles=Kinkaku-ji
```

For more than one title use pipe to separate them: `titles=Kinkaku-ji|Paris|...`

Comment: You are just great :)